# Changing value of custom select option - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need assistance changing the value of a custom-select box.  I cannot use JQuery because I already have a change() function hooked up to it.

How can I change the value of the select box in Javascript?

This is my custom select function:

```
$.fn.customSelect = function() {
if ( $(this).length ) {
    $(this).find('select').attr('selectedIndex',-1).change(function() {
        var optionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $(this).siblings('label').text(optionText)
    });
}
```

};

I have tried:

```
var field = document.getElementById('test5');
field.value = '2';
field.focus();
```

This will select the option, but it will not show up as the default option (hopefully you guys can understand this haha).

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a fiddle example of what trying to do [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PQpeH/1/)

You need to invoke the change event to run the plugin code, also **name** the change event:

```
$.fn.customSelect = function() {
    if ( $(this).length ) {
        $(this).find('select').attr('selectedIndex',-1).bind('change.customSelect', function() {
            var optionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            $(this).siblings('label').text(optionText)
        });
    }
};
```

**Trigger like this:**

```
$('#select1').val('1').trigger('change.customSelect');
```

Comment: Yeah, I have been using the change event, but there's another function that gets called in the change event... which causes it to be called twice.  I might have to change the implementation around if there is no way to do this in javascript

Comment: @yookd - I updated the fiddle so you can see it not trigger another bound change event.

Comment: Ah, this requires a lot of changes throughout the site (we have many select boxes, unfortunately).  Thank you for this though, I can use this if I have the time to change everything.